# Android how to set windowanimation programmatically

Tags: android, animation

I can set animation do dialog using xml like following

```
Dialog myDialog;
        myDialog.getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.style.Animations_sample);
```

How can I add programmatically created animation to Dialog?
What I mean is I created a animation like following

```
 AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(true);

        TranslateAnimation a = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.ABSOLUTE,200, Animation.ABSOLUTE,200,
                Animation.ABSOLUTE,200, Animation.ABSOLUTE,200);
        a.setDuration(1000);
        animationSet.addAnimation(a);
```

how can I set `animationSet` to `myDialog`?

Thanks in adv.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by programmatically.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to google:

windowAnimations

A style resource defining the animations to use for this window. This must be a system resource; it can not be an application resource because the window manager does not have access to applications.

Answer (score 0):

This must be a system resource - not true . If in device is enable WINDOW_ANIMATION_SCALE or
TRANSITION_ANIMATION_SCALE you can use app animation res.